# Login with Facebook in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to login with Facebook with ***Symfony 3.4***. I am following this [tutorial](https://hugo-soltys.com/blog/use-facebook-or-google-to-login-to-your-symfony-website-with-hwioauthbundle) but unfortunately facing this error

> Unrecognized field: facebookId

I have tried this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524045/unrecognized-field-facebookid) but this couldn't fixed it for me.

Here is my code

***config.yml***

```
hwi_oauth:
firewall_names: [secured_area]
fosub:
    properties:
        facebook: facebookId
resource_owners:
    facebook:
        type:                facebook
        client_id:           471421726653730
        client_secret:       4c0d30bfa73e2ec0ec3e94a0f9cab0e1
        options:
            display: popup
            auth_type: rerequest
            csrf: true
```

***security.yml***

```
        secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
            #always_remember_me : true
        form_login:
            provider:   cms_dashboard_user
            login_path: cms_myuser_login
            check_path: cms_myuser_login_check
        logout:
            path:   cms_myuser_logout
            target: cms_myuser_login
            invalidate_session: false
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/secured/login_facebook"
            login_path:        fos_user_security_login
            failure_path:      fos_user_security_login
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service
```

***services.yml***

```
    my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:
    class: CMS\FrontUserBundle\Provider\MyFOSUBProvider
    arguments:
        - '@fos_user.user_manager'
        - { facebook: facebookId }
        - '@doctrine'
```

***routing.yml***

```
facebook_login:
    path: /secured/login_facebook
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login
```

***Front User Entity***

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="facebook_id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $facebookId;

    /**
     * Set facebookId.
     *
     * @param string|null $facebookId
     *
     * @return FrontUser
     */
    public function setFacebookId($facebookId = null)
    {
       $this->facebookId = $facebookId;

       return $this;
    }

   /**
    * Get facebookId.
    *
    * @return string|null
    */
    public function getFacebookId()
    {
        return $this->facebookId;
    }
```

***Provider Class***

```
    <?php

namespace CMS\FrontUserBundle\Provider;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider;
use CMS\FrontUserBundle\Entity\FrontUser;

class MyFOSUBProvider extends FOSUBUserProvider
{
    private $doctrine;

    /**
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager
     * @param array $properties
     * @param Registry $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, array $properties, $doctrine)
    {
        parent::__construct($userManager, $properties);

        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);

        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));

        $email = $response->getEmail();
        // check if we already have this user
        $existing = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array('email' => $email));
        if ($existing instanceof FrontUser) {
            // in case of Facebook login, update the facebook_id
            if ($property == "facebookId") {
                $existing->setFacebookId($username);
            }
            $this->userManager->updateUser($existing);

            return $existing;
        }

        // if we don't know the user, create it
        if (null === $user || null === $username) {
            /** @var User $user */
            $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
            $nick = "johndoe"; // to be changed

            $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
            $user->setEnabled(true);

            $user->setUsername($nick);
            $user->setUsernameCanonical($nick);
            $user->setPassword(sha1(uniqid()));
            $user->addRole('ROLE_USER');

            if ($property == "facebookId") {
                $user->setFacebookId($username);
            }
            if ($property == "googleId") {
                $user->setGoogleId($username);
            }
        }

        $user->setEmail($response->getEmail());
        $user->setFirstname($response->getFirstName());
        $user->setLastname($response->getLastName());

        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

***fos_user configuration***

```
fos_user:
db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
firewall_name:  main
user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User


group:
    group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
    group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager # If you're using doctrine orm (use sonata.user.mongodb.group_manager for mongodb)

service:
    user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager

from_email:
    address: "noreply@theemirates.com"
    sender_name: "The Emirates Brand"
```

Comment: Can you share the config.yml where fos_user is configured please ?

Comment: Is that your actually facebook client_id and client_secret?  If so, you should probably stop whatever you are doing and generate new ones.

Comment: @pbenard I have added fos_user configuration too.

Comment: @Cerad I have tried generate new keys but no luck.

Comment: In the config, fosuser user class is pointed to a sonata user class, is this your entity with facebookId ?

Comment: @pbenard no I am trying to add user through front user entity.

Comment: Ok, but your oauth config is using @fos_user.user_manager, so I think it take the one you give in the fos_user config....

Comment: @pbenard so can you please guide me how can I connect front user entity?

Comment: Can you share your whole entity file please...

It should extends the fos_user base user class, and after, your set it in the config.yml under the fos_user node

Comment: @pbenard thankyou for your time :) Solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by setting query on my `front user entity` in provider class and added container in service.

***services.yml***

```
my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:
    class: CMS\FrontUserBundle\Provider\MyFOSUBProvider
    arguments:
        - '@fos_user.user_manager'
        - { facebook: facebookId }
        - '@doctrine'
        - '@service_container'
```

***provider class***

```
      <?php

    namespace CMS\FrontUserBundle\Provider;

    use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
    use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
    use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider;
    use CMS\FrontUserBundle\Entity\FrontUser;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

    class MyFOSUBProvider extends FOSUBUserProvider
    {

        private $doctrine;
        private $container;
        private $router;


        /**
         * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager
         * @param array $properties
         * @param Registry $doctrine
         */
        public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, array $properties, $doctrine,$container, $router)
        {

            parent::__construct($userManager, $properties);
            $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
            $this->container = $container;
            $this->router = $router;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
        {
            $username = $response->getUsername();
            $property = $this->getProperty($response);
            $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();

            $user = $em->getRepository('CMSFrontUserBundle:FrontUser')->findOneBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));

            if (!$response->getEmail()) {
                return new RedirectResponse('cms_myuser_login');
            }
            $email = $response->getEmail();


            // check if we already have this user
            $existing = $em->getRepository('CMSFrontUserBundle:FrontUser')->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
            if ($existing instanceof FrontUser) {
                // in case of Facebook login, update the facebook_id
                if ($property == "facebookId") {
                    $existing->setFacebookId($username);
                    $em->flush();
                    $frontuser = $existing;
                }
            }

            // if we don't know the user, create it
            if (null === $user || null === $username) {
                ///** @var User $user */
                $user = new FrontUser();
                $nick = "johndoe"; // to be changed

                $user->setCreateAt(new \DateTime());
                $user->setEnabled(true);

                $user->setUsername($nick);
                $user->setPassword(sha1(uniqid()));

                if ($property == "facebookId") {
                    $user->setFacebookId($username);
                }

                $user->setEmail($response->getEmail());
                $user->setUsertype('individual');
                $user->setFirstname($response->getFirstName());
                $user->setLastname($response->getLastName());
                $user->setContactNumber('0000000000');

                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
                $frontuser = $user;

            }
            $user = $em->getRepository('CMSFrontUserBundle:FrontUser')->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
            if ($frontuser && $frontuser->getEnabled() == true && $frontuser->getEmail()==$user->getEmail()) {
                $session = new Session();
                $firewall = 'secured_area';
                $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($frontuser, null, $firewall, array('ROLE_DASHBOARD_USER'));
                $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
                $session->set('_security_' . $firewall, serialize($token));
                $session->save();
                return new RedirectResponse('cms_myuser_dashboard');
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: @pbenard yeah sure :)